# Aptana Studio 3: can't make my own PHP Templates

Tags: php, templates, aptana

How do you make your own PHP templates for Aptana Studio 3 ?

I googled for it and the following ways do not work:
- Go to Commands - PHP - Edit this bundle

This does not work because when you click "Edit this bundle", nothing happens

Another possible solution:
- Go to Window - Preferences - Aptana Studio - Editors - PHP

This also doesn't work, because the only subitem of PHP that shows up is "Libraries". Nor are there are any other options in the detail fields for templating.

Right now I'm clueless. Do I have to install something first in order to enable PHP Templating?

Or are there any hacks that could work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Go to Commands - PHP - Edit this bundle"

Look in your projects list, it opened it as a project called 'PHP'. Whenever you save your changes, the changes will be automatically available.

Comment: I can't get other templates to get installed, but that could be due to the fact I don't know any ruby syntax. But I've now managed to edit the standard PHP template and change the <?php phpinfo(); ?> template with my own, so that works now. Thanks for this tip.